# The number of roots of the sum of radicals

Tags: real-analysis

Let $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $$-\infty < a_1 < b_1 < a_2 < b_2 < a_3 < b_3<\cdots<a_n<b_n<+\infty$$ and $k_i\in \mathbb{R}, i=1,2,\ldots,n$. Is there any information about how many roots the function $$f(x)=k_1\sqrt{x-a_1} + k_2 \sqrt{x-a_2} + \cdots+k_n\sqrt{x-a_n}$$ for $x\geqslant a_n$ or the function $$g(x)=k_1(\sqrt{x-a_1}-\sqrt{x-b_1})+k_2(\sqrt{x-a_2}-\sqrt{x-b_2})+\cdots+k_n(\sqrt{x-a_n}-\sqrt{x-b_n})$$ for $x\geqslant b_n$ can have?

Comment: Taking the product of the $2^{n-1}$ polynomials $k_1\sqrt{x-a_1}\pm k_2\sqrt{x-a_2}\pm\cdots \pm k_n\sqrt{x-a_n}$ gives a polynomial of degree $2^{n-2}$, so this is a bound on the number of roots. But this doesn't use the condition $x\geq a_n$.

Comment: Thank you! I have added the condition $x\geqslant a_n$ to stay in the area of real-analysis. But now i think that for me it's enough to have any statement like the Fundamental theorem of algebra but for functions $f(z)=k_1\sqrt{z−a_1}+k_2\sqrt{z−a_2}+\cdots +k_n\sqrt{z−a_n},\quad k_i,a_i,z∈\mathbb{C}$. Is there such statement like $f$ can have at most $n$ complex-roots? Or something like this.

Comment: You mean, how many real roots?

Comment: Possibly useful: Arthur Cayley (1821-1895), [*On polyzomal curves, otherwise the curves* $\sqrt{U} + \sqrt{V} + \&\text{c.} = 0$](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22On+polyzomal+curves%2C+otherwise+the+curves%22+Cayley&filter=0), **Transactions of the Royal Society of Edinburgh** 25 (1869), pp. 1-110. [archive.org copy](https://archive.org/details/transactionsofro25royal/page/n21/mode/2up). I also cited this in a comment to the MSE question [free software for radical algebraic equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4510791/13130), a question/answers that might also be of interest.

Comment: @YCor, Actually I meant complex root.  Maybe it's some obvious question from complex analysis, but i have never met it in any of standard literature.

Comment: @Dave L Renfro, Thank you very much for the link! I think my question is from another area of math.

Comment: @eN.meshok if you mean complex root, you might need to specify the domain on which you define this function. For instance, asking whether the function $\sqrt{z}-i$ has a root at $-1$ is ambiguous if the domain is not specified.

Comment: @YCor, Since $f(z)=\sqrt{z}$ is well defined on the whole complex plane, I thought we could take the whole $\mathbb{C}$ as a domain. Isn't it true?

Comment: @eN.meshok how do you define the $\sqrt{z}$ for $z=e^{it}$, $t$ real?

Comment: @YCor, $\sqrt{z}=e^{i\frac{t+2\pi k}{2}}, k=0,1.$

Comment: @eN.meshok this is not a function. A function maps an element to a single element.

Answer (score 1):

In the case when $n=1, 2, 3, 4$ the number of roots of $f$ is at most $1, 1, 2, 4$ respectively. This can be seen by squaring $f$ several times. For inctance, let $n=3$, then
$$k_1\sqrt{x-a_1}+k_2\sqrt{x-a_2}+k_3\sqrt{x-a_3}=0$$
$$k_1^2(x-a_1)+k_2^2(x-a_2)+2k_1\sqrt{x-a_1}k_2\sqrt{x-a_2}=k_3^2(x-a_3)$$
$$4k_1^2(x-a_1)k_2^2(x-a_2)=\left(k_3^2(x-a_3)-k_1^2(x-a_1)-k_2^2(x-a_2)\right)^2$$
So, we have a polynomial of the second degree.
But this technique can't be applied to $n=5,6,...$.